# Area51 and 4chan?

Tags: support, area-51, inappropriate-content

I came across this proposal: **[4Chan](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14311/4chan)** and my internal flags went off.

For those of you who don't know, 4Chan *does* have interesting discussions on gaming and is a large producer of internet memes, however, it also has a lot of hentai, porn, and other inappropriate-for-work subjects.

Should sites like 4Chan be allowed on StackExchange/Area51?

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd list one of your pros as a con.

Comment: Hey man, don't call all hentai and porn distasteful like that. Only the good stuff is! Geez.

Comment: What better for a site whose users value anonymity than a separate site that requires authentication!

Comment: @Shog9: stack exchange doesn't require any kind of authentication. You can ask and answer questions without registering. Only the optional features (such as accepting answers or voting) requires you to register.

Comment: What is 4chan??

Comment: @Tim: A site you should not look for on a corporate network.

Comment: @Kop: area51 however *does* require authentication.

Comment: Bad move.  Bad BAD move.  In fact, its probably too late.  They sniff the proposal and the proposal gets rocketed to #1.  Remove it and they sniff THAT out...

Comment: @Will if Meta/StackExchange can settle on what to do regarding the other proposals mentioned, they have nothing to complain about, and it's not prejudiced ( anymore >_o ... )

Comment: @rlb  They never forgive.  They never forget.

Answer (score 6):

Meh; there's no mention of porn or /b/ in the proposal itself... While there are at least three proposals already on *explicitly* sex-oriented topics. If that bothers you, then *don't follow them*.